# How to draw a Normal Distribution Curve (Bell curve) using CSS and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

1. It doesn't need to be mathematically accurate.
2. It needs to be symmetrical.
3. It needs to have a color gradient in it.
4. I need to dynamically add a point on the curve. ( But I think I can
   do that by myself- but any help would be highly appreciated)

*I am a newbie, which is my fault(I am not trying garnering sympathy), i am trying my best to do this.*

I have been trying to do it for some time now. I just cant get the uphill curve correctly in SVG, I tried to type it out and use Inkscape but I wan't able to achieve it.

Comment: Let me remind you that this is a website where we help people; if you want us to write you some code, then you might as well pay us. Show us what you've done, and we'll try to fix the code and help you after that. Try something at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function NormalDensityZx(x, Mean, StdDev) {
  var a = x - Mean;
  return Math.exp(-(a * a) / (2 * StdDev * StdDev)) / (Math.sqrt(2 * Math.PI) * StdDev);
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Calculates Q(x), the right tail area under the Standard Normal Curve. 
function StandardNormalQx(x) {
  if (x === 0) // no approximation necessary for 0
    return 0.50;

  var t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, qx;
  var negative = false;
  if (x < 0) {
    x = -x;
    negative = true;
  }
  t1 = 1 / (1 + (0.2316419 * x));
  t2 = t1 * t1;
  t3 = t2 * t1;
  t4 = t3 * t1
  t5 = t4 * t1;
  qx = NormalDensityZx(x, 0, 1) * ((0.319381530 * t1) + (-0.356563782 * t2) + (1.781477937 * t3) + (-1.821255978 * t4) + (1.330274429 * t5));

  if (negative == true)
    qx = 1 - qx;
  return qx;
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Calculates P(x), the left tail area under the Standard Normal Curve, which is 1 - Q(x). 
function StandardNormalPx(x) {
  return 1 - StandardNormalQx(x);
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Calculates A(x), the area under the Standard Normal Curve between +x and -x
function StandardNormalAx(x) {
  return 1 - (2 * StandardNormalQx(Math.abs(x)));
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Define values where to put vertical lines at
var verticals = [-1.4, -0.2, 1.2

];
/**
 * Calculate data
 */
var chartData = [];
for (var i = -5; i < 5.1; i += 0.1) {
  var dp = {
    category: i,
    value: NormalDensityZx(i, 0, 1)
  };
  if (verticals.indexOf(Math.round(i * 10) / 10) !== -1) {
    dp.vertical = dp.value;
  }
  chartData.push(dp);
}

/**
 * Create a chart
 */
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "serial",
  "theme": "light",
  "dataProvider": chartData,
  "precision": 2,
  "valueAxes": [{
    "gridAlpha": 0.2,
    "dashLength": 0
  }],
  "startDuration": 1,
  "graphs": [{
    "balloonText": "[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b>",
    "lineThickness": 3,
    "valueField": "value"
  }, {
    "balloonText": "",
    "fillAlphas": 1,
    "type": "column",
    "valueField": "vertical",
    "fixedColumnWidth": 2,
    "labelText": "[[value]]",
    "labelOffset": 20
  }],
  "chartCursor": {
    "categoryBalloonEnabled": false,
    "cursorAlpha": 0,
    "zoomable": false
  },
  "categoryField": "category",
  "categoryAxis": {
    "gridAlpha": 0.05,
    "startOnAxis": true,
    "tickLength": 5,
    "labelFunction": function(label, item) {
      return '' + Math.round(item.dataContext.category * 10) / 10;
    }
  }

});
```

```css
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  font-size: 11px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script><script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

I hope this helps you. thank you